# Get method search form with multiple fields and friendly URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-rewriting, get

I have a search form with 3 input fields that will return results on the same page. I have rewritten the url to make it look like this:

```
http://www.demosite.com/search/input1/input2/input3
```

the form submits data like this:

```
http://www.demosite.com?field1=input1&field2=input2&field3=input3
```

As I said before URL rewriting is done I just need the form to submit in the friendly manner to the same page.

I have managed to find a solution for a form with one input field

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="http://www.demosite.com/index.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="location.href='http://www.demosite.com/search/' + encodeURIComponent(this.field1.value); return false;">
```

But I cannot make it work with 3 input fields, here is my beginner solution adapted using the good solution:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="http://www.demosite.com/index.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="location.href='http://www.demosite.com/search/' + encodeURIComponent(this.field1.value) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.field2.value) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.field3.value); return false;">
```

Comment: What happens when you hit submit?  What URL are you redirected to?

Comment: The attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is used primarily when uploading files in forms, so you may not need it here. But, if you do, then your `method` attribute should be `post`, not `get`.
Also give more details of what'`s happen when you press submit and the rest of the form fields?

Comment: @DoctorMick when I submit the url is the old one.